# Loud squeak in the start of Kali

Tags: kali-linux, audio, startup

When I start Kali Linux, there is a loud squeak. How it can be turned off. Found on the Internet, about Debian but there is no necessary file (`fbdev-blacklist.conf`). Tell me how I can turn off this squeak in the boot. Help please

Comment: All sorts of comments about your mouse spring to mind, but I'll desist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming sound comes from speakers, that is sound card init.
It may be very hard to do anything with that - as drivers are part of the kernel.
You need to read about your specific sound card - driver, there might be something you can do. fbdev (framebuffer device) typically has nothing to do with sound card.